# StructureMap registration

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

Imagine interface

- IRepository
- IFooRepository : IRepository
- IBarRepository : IRepository

With associated Repository:

- FooRepository : RepositoryBase, IFooRepository
- BarRepository : RepositoryBase, IBarRepository

I'm trying to do generic registration with structure map to register all my repository in one Registry to call my IoC with IFooRepository

```
public class DataRegistry : Registry
    {
        public DataRegistry()
        {
            Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssemblyContainingType<RepositoryBase>();
                x.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<RepositoryBase>();
                //Todo Register EndWith Repository as ImplementedInterface
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will enable you to resolve IFooRepository as an instance of FooRepository:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.AssemblyContainingType<RepositoryBase>();
    x.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<RepositoryBase>();
    x.WithDefaultConventions();

});
```

`WithDefaultConventions` connects all interfaces with classes having the same name (except the I).
`SingleImplementationsOfInterface` will do in your case as well.